# How to store the results of an array matrix into a smaller array c#

Tags: c#, arrays, class, math, matrix

I need to add a value which would be either p1(payoff one) or p2 (payoff two) to the surrounding four neighbours of a value in a matrix that'll then be printed into a new array matrix. If it's 1 then p1 will need to be added to it's neighbours or if its 0 then p2 will be added to its neighbours. I've tried to do this approach with a nested for loop but my 'if' statement in my for loop is giving me errors and Im not sure where to go next with it.

```
  class MainClass
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int m, n, i, j, p1, p2;

        // rows and columns of the matrix+
        m = 3;
        n = 3;

        //Payoff matrix
        p1 = 10; //cheat payoff matrix
        p2 = 5; //co-op payoff matrix




        int[,] arr = new int[3, 3];


        Console.Write("To enter 1 it means to co-operate" );
        Console.Write("To enter 0 it means to cheat");

        Console.Write("Enter elements of the Matrix: ");
        for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                arr[i, j] = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());

            }
        }






        Console.WriteLine("Printing Matrix: ");
        for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                Console.Write(arr[i, j] + "\t");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }




        // how to change the values of the matrix

        int[] payoffMatrix = new int[4];

        for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                if(arr[i,j] == 1)
                {
                    arr[i, j] = arr[i - 1, j] , arr[i + 1, j] , arr[i, j - 1] , arr[i, j + 1];
                }

            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```

The result of the neighbouring values need to be printed into the payoff matrix aswell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly you need to make a copy of your array first. Because otherwise you would read e.g. "1" from a array position (i + 1) from the current iteration. That's probably not what you want.
Then you just set the desired values in your for-loop. You need some bound checking, because e.g. arrNew[i - 1] will only be accessible if i > 0

this gives you something like:

```
        int[,] arrNew = arr.Clone() as int[,]; //creates a copy of arr

        for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                if (arr[i, j] == 1)
                {
                    if (i > 0) //bounds checking
                    {
                        arrNew[i - 1, j] = 1;
                    }

                    if (i < m - 1) //bounds checking
                    {
                        arrNew[i + 1, j] = 1;
                    }

                    if (j > 0) //bounds checking
                    {
                        arrNew[i, j - 1] = 1;
                    }

                    if (j < n - 1) //bounds checking
                    {
                        arrNew[i, j + 1] = 1;
                    }

                }

            }
        }
```

For a matrix:

```
0 0 0
0 1 0
0 0 0
```

the result would be

```
0 1 0
1 1 1
0 1 0
```

Comment: Ahh Yeah I understand it now. How does the .clone work? if i was to do payoffMatrix = arr.clone ? will that work

Comment: It should. Instead of using the clone function you could iterate your array and copy the values manually to a new array with the same dimensions. Please consider to accept the answer if it helped you. Thx.

Comment: Will accept as an answer, thanks for the help, im just struggling with now printing the values from the payoff matrix? Do i just need a console.writeLine on the outside for loop?

Comment: Sorted my previous question. I'd like to lastly just ask would anyone know how to randomly replace a value from the new matrix into the original array

Comment: 1. You should iterate over your array and print every value (write/writeline) 2. Check out Random.Next(n) (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?view=netframework-4.8) this will give you a pseudo random number between 0 and n. This number can be used to generate an adress in your array arr[rand.next(3), rand.next(3)] . Something like that.

Comment: You already have the code for printing. I would suggest to move it to a separate function so it is reusable. And you should detect the size of the array with arr.GetLength(d) where d is your dimension (0 or 1 for 2D arrays). This way you can print any 2D array.